# Get selected value from dropdown with jQuery and title

Tags: jquery

To get the selected value from a dropdown with ID is easy:

```
$("#ComboBox option:selected").text()
```

However I can't use ID and need to get it by title/a select element, how do I do that? I tried something like: `var item_level = $('select:contains("Item Level")').text()`

but wasn't very successfull.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: with var item_level = $("select[title='Item Level']").text();
I get all the options, how do I get the selected one only?

Comment: how many select inputs you have? is it generated dynamically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with your comment you can select the selected option only in

```
$("select[title=Item Level] option:selected").text();
```

Comment: Hi Rob, that gives me a pop up with nothing in it
var item_level = $("select[title='Item Level']option:selected").text();
alert(item_level);

It is only 4 options and the dropdownlist works as a hidden filter

Comment: copy exactly what I placed in the snippet. don't put `'` in `Item Level` and put space between ] and `option`